# Heroku script hosting

Tags: selenium, heroku

I am trying to find a place to host a script. I need a browser open for it to run. My questions for Heroku are is it possible to:

- Operate a Selenium script non-headless (with a browser window open)?
- Continue to run even if my local computer goes into sleep mode or loses internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a virtual machine that can run a GUI browser which will be open to a page running client-side Javascript, right? If so, Heroku won't help. Heroku is more for hosting APIs than this.

I'd recommend looking at AWS, EC2 or AWS-AWS might help.